# Magento not sending shipment emails - other emails working

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, email, ce-1.9.0.1, transactional-mail

I am having problems with Magento emails:

The cron sends the Order Confirmation and Invoice emails fine - but NOT the shipment emails.

They are definitely enabled in *Configuration/Sales/Sales Emails*.
(I have also added a 'copy to' email address to check what is being sent out.)

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: maybe the file cannot be opened, you could enable some logging under System / Configuration / Developer -> `Log settings` and take a look in `var/log/system.log`, please update your question when you have some more information

Comment: The logging was already enabled. What information would be useful? I don't understand the system.log at all...

Comment: exact same thing M1934 ... strange is that like 1 our of every 40 are sent. So we are not seeing none, but some ...